# Secondary Query Is Breaking Main Query

Tags: get-posts

I registered a Custom Post type called "quote" and I am trying to show a single random quote on every page of my Wordpress site.  I'm pulling out a single quote with the following code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'quote', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$posts = get_posts( $args );

//The code between here and the next comment doesn't really matter.  I can remove it
//and the problem will still exist.  As soon as I make the get_posts() call above
// I get the problem   
if (sizeof($posts) > 0) {
    echo '<p class="quote"><span class="quote-sym">&quot;</span>'.$posts[0]->post_content.'<span class="quote-sym">&quot;</span></p>';
    $author = trim(get_field("author", $posts[0]->ID));
    if (!empty($author)) {echo '<p class="author">- '.$author.'</p>';}
 } 
 //End block
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

This works and I'm able to show a single random quote. (I'm using the advanced custom fields plugin which adds the get_field method in the code above.)  However, my main loop content gets corrupted.  Instead of showing the main loop content on the page, my quote is repeated a second time in it's place.  This is the code I'm using for my main loop.

```
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">             
          <div class="entry">
          <?php the_content(); ?></div><!-- end entry -->
     </div> <!--end post -->
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

If I remove the code that displays the quote, my main loop content gets restored.  I thought calling `wp_reset_postdata()` was the key to using a secondary loop with the main loop, but it doesn't seem to help in this case.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` for `get_posts()` because it does not actually modify global variable `$wp_query`.

`$posts` though is a global variable used by WordPress. Change that to a new name and what you have should work.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'quote', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$quote_posts = get_posts( $args );

if (sizeof($quote_posts) > 0) {
    echo '<p class="quote"><span class="quote-sym">&quot;</span>'.$quote_posts[0]->post_content.'<span class="quote-sym">&quot;</span></p>';
    $author = trim(get_field("author", $quote_posts[0]->ID));
    if (!empty($author)) {echo '<p class="author">- '.$author.'</p>';}
 } 
 //End block
```

Comment: you are right about the global and specific and recognizable naming always a good idea

Comment: Good catch.  This was exactly the issue!  I'll return and mark this as the correct answer once my reputation increases.  Thank you very much.